# Deep Copy of Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, oop, computer-science, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I'm trying to create a deep copy of object but the complier is throwing this error[image]

As I'm beginner in C# and want to grip over these concepts of oop so your valuble answer explaining this concept would be highly appreciated

Comment: Please don’t show screenshot of code. Include it as formatted code text. And make sure you provide a minimum example that others can reproduce.

Comment: It sounds straightforward. The quadratic construction does not accept arguments. So you probably want a = b instead?

Comment: It seems like you may be coming from a background of working with [tag:c++] maybe? Realise that different languages work differently and there aren't "universal truths" about how these languages work. So, for instance, C# doesn't create copy constructors by default (nor does it need to in general)

Comment: In C# you'd do this via implementing an [IClonable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Giving `Quadratic` its own input and output methods is not a good design. Those are unrelated to the mathematical concept represented by the type. It should represent the values (A, B, C) and implement operations on those values (solve?), if any. As such, it would be better as a `struct` than a `class`, and making a copy (which should suffice to be shallow) is a matter of simple assignment, `Quadratic copy = original;` If there's a string representation you want to support, implement Parse/TryParse and ToString, but that string should come from *anywhere*.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for everyone for your contribution in this regard

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see the ctor of the quadratic class, it seems you are missing an overload that accepts one parameter.

Like so.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Class1
    {

        public Class1()
        {

        }

        public Class1(int input)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Quadratic class doesn't have an overload for its own type to create deep copy. You have few options to create deep copy of your classes.

1. Create the class by setting its properties yourself in the constructor
2. Use the MemberwiseClone() method.
3. Serialize it and deserialize it again. You can do this with built-in JSON serializer that's located in the System.Text.Json namespace or with Protobuf. (Do **NOT** use BinaryFormatter to do this. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) article for more information.)

```cs
public class Quadratic
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }

    public Quadratic()
    {
    }

    public Quadratic(Quadratic quadraticToCopy)
    {
        A = quadraticToCopy.A;
        B = quadraticToCopy.B;
        C = quadraticToCopy.C;
    }

    public Quadratic CreateDeepCopy1() => new Quadratic(this);
    public Quadratic CreateDeepCopy2() => (Quadratic)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

And then you can use it like this;

```cs
var originalQuadratic = new Quadratic();
originalQuadratic.Input();
originalQuadratic.Display();

var deepCopiedQuadratic1 = originalQuadratic.CreateDeepCopy1();
var deepCopiedQuadratic2 = originalQuadratic.CreateDeepCopy2();
```